# What issues with LongPathsEnabled have you seen?

Tags: windows, filesystems, windows-server-2016

We have a number of reporting websites that our agency publishes both internally to our organization as well as to the public facing web. Most of the time, we neither control the names nor the folder structure, and a number of them have pushed past [the long filename limit of Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#maximum-path-length-limitation) (around 256 characters). The first website affected is a simple static site with PDFs (with a few spreadsheets) and pages describing the documents. This time of year (January 1 to April 30) is the busy season for our customers and we're very hesitant to make any server changes at this time.

[Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=registry) mentions changing a registry key setting at `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem LongPathsEnabled (Type: REG_DWORD)`. The article also mentions support for Group Policy control at `Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Filesystem > Enable NTFS long paths` for organization-wide implementation.

IIS supports urls up to about 2048 characters, so we are not limited there.

What issues, if any, could there be with setting `LongPathsEnabled` to 1? Have you seen any?

What issues, if any, have you seen with the Group Policy setting?

I think this question is related:
[LongPathsEnabled Setting ignored on Windows Server 2016](https://serverfault.com/questions/1032586/longpathsenabled-setting-ignored-on-windows-server-2016)

Comment: *"What issues with LongPathsEnabled have you seen?"* sounds like a poll and soliciting anecdotes, rather than a genuine technical problem to you want to solve. That is unlikely to generate good answers. - I'm more familiar with Linux but in general Microsoft has a long standing tradition for maintaining backward compatibility with previous and even legacy products (or attempts to) and this might be a setting that breaks (backward) compatibility versions older than Windows 10, version 1607 and others.